# Want to remove \n from len

Tags: python, list, output

here is my task:

You are provided a books.txt file, which includes the book titles, each one written on a separate line.
Read the title one by one and output the code for each book on a separate line.

For example, if the books.txt file contains:

```
Some book
Another book
```

Your program should output:

```
S9
A12
```

```
file = open("/usercode/files/books.txt", "r")

with file as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for i in lines:
        count = len(i)
        count = str(count - 1)
        print(i[0]+count)
    

file.close()
```

and this outputs everything correct but the last line because i[#lastLine] is done after the last count if that makes any sense?(could be completely wrong I am learning)

Basically I want to know where I am going wrong in my code. I believe it is the way I structured the for i in lines part and should have handled the \n in a different way to

count = len(i)
count = str(count - 1)

ANSWER

Thank you for informing me, adding i = i.strip() strips new lines aka \n which sorted the problem!

Working code:

```
file = open("/usercode/files/books.txt", "r")

with file as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for i in lines:
        i = i.strip('\n') #Strips new lines aka \n
        count = str(len(i))
        print(i[0]+count)
    

file.close()
```

Comment: How would I use it within my code I haven't learnt it yet. Would it be like line.strip('\n')

Comment: By default, `.strip()` strips new lines

Comment: Put `i = i.strip()` as the first line of the `for` loop. By default it removes all whitespace at the beginning and end of the string, which includes newlines. If you just want to remove the newline, use `i.strip('\n')`

Comment: Amazing, that works thanks so much everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `strip()` on i to remove the new lines.

*strip - Returns a copy of the string with the leading and trailing characters removed.*
[Python docs strip](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/strip.html)

you can cast your count as a str() to print.

*str()
Returns a string containing a printable representation of an object.*

[Python docs str](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/)
As comments point out, suggest also changing `i` to `line` for readability.

```
file = open("books.txt", "r")

with file as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        count = str(len(line.strip()))
        print(line[0]+count)
    

file.close()
```

Comment: Also, format strings would make this cleaner.  `print(f"{line[0]}{len(line.strip()) - 1}")`

Comment: Thank you I do need to work on cleaning my code up